# What are the steps to migrate an enterprise application running in J2EE to Spring 5.0 with minimal impact?

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, struts, ejb-3.0

We are interested to migrate our **EJB+WebSphere+JPA+Struts** application stack to Spring 5.0 .

Already we discussed the pros and cons of this. Now we decided to move to **Spring+Tomcat+Struts** stack.
We have very short term allowed for this project . So , we want migrate with minimal impact.

What are the possible ways? I goggled and found only just discussion , there is no much useful information in Internet.

Please let us know if anyone is having real-time experience on this.

[Migrating from EJB3 to Spring, Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211521/migrating-from-ejb3-to-spring-hibernate)

Comment: No way, Struts is much reacher on the frontend and backend.

Comment: @RomanC , this is our requirement . Someway, we need to do this.

Comment: Requirement is for whom is required.

Answer (score 1):

No way, Struts is much reacher on the frontend and backend. Because it's different frameworks you have to rewrite everything. You can only keep in mind MVC pattern. The Codding is different.

The migration is *not* a integration. Even if it's possible to integrate both then it is not a way to keep WOW application running in the production. This kind of applications never get migrated completely.